# How do I run mysqld as a regular non-daemon program?

Tags: unix, mysql, sockets

I'd like to run a local copy of mysql, to keep software development environments isolated.  However, I can't seem to get the mysqld server to start up.

I've created a database directory with `mysql_install_db`.  I've figured out that I need a socket file, and how to specify the path.  However, mysqld keeps reporting that it can't find or open the file.

```
/path/to/mysqld --datadir=./db/mysql --socket=./tmp/mysqld.sock
```

(snip)

```
130102 9:54:28 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: No such file or directory
130102 9:54:28 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: ./tmp/mysqld.sock ?
```

Answer (score 4):

The socket file needs to be specified with a fully qualified path, although the datadir can stay relative.

```
/path/to/mysqld --datadir=./db/mysql --socket=/Users/jlove/myproject/tmp/mysqld.sock
```